# kivymd expansion panel - how to create panels with different content

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Eorking with kivymd, and trying to create an expansion panel list with different content in each of the panels.

Tried to write an if statement inside the `def on_start(self)`, like this:

```
def on_start(self):
    for i in range(len(category_list)):
        self.root.ids.box.add_widget(
            MDExpansionPanel(
                if i==0:
                    content=Content1()
                else:
                    content=Content2(),
                    icon=f"{icon_list[i]}",
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                        text=category_list[i].upper(),
                        secondary_text=category_secondary_list[i],
                )
            )
        )
```

but didnt work. any idea how to tackle this?

my full code below:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd import images_path
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelTwoLine

KV = '''
<Content>
    adaptive_height: True

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: "10dp"
        padding:"10dp" 
        MDLabel:
            text:"text"

Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDToolbar:
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                id: box

'''
  
class Content(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


category_list = ["pink", "purple", "yellow", "blue", "green","black", "white"]
category_secondary_list = ["pinkpinkpinkpinkpinkpinkpinkpinkpinkpinkpink",
                                  "purplepurplepurplepurplepurple",
                                  "yellowyellowyellowyellowyellow",
                                  "blueblueblueblue",
                                  "greengreengreengreen",
                                  "blackblackblackblack",
                                  "whitewhitewhitewhitewhite"]

icon_list = ["water-drop.png", "fast-food.png", "medetation.png", "cigarette.png", "band-aid.png", "mood.png",
                    "exercise.png"]


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(len(category_list)):
            self.root.ids.box.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                        content=Content(),
                        icon=f"{icon_list[i]}",
                        panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                            text=category_list[i].upper(),
                            secondary_text=category_secondary_list[i],
                    )
                )
            )


Test().run()
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically invalid Python:

```
        MDExpansionPanel(
            if i==0:
                content=Content1()
            else:
                content=Content2(),
                icon=f"{icon_list[i]}",
                panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                    text=category_list[i].upper(),
                    secondary_text=category_secondary_list[i],
            )
        )
```

That's bad. Why? Because `if ...:` and `else:` statements are *statements.* They can't be embedded as expressions in a parameter list. Instead, you want...

Syntactically valid Python:

```
def on_start(self):
    for i in range(len(category_list)):
        self.root.ids.box.add_widget(
            MDExpansionPanel(content=Content1())
            if i==0 else
            MDExpansionPanel(
                content=Content2(),
                icon=f"{icon_list[i]}",
                panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelTwoLine(
                    text=category_list[i].upper(),
                    secondary_text=category_secondary_list[i],
                )
            )
        )
```

That's good. Just invert your workflow by embedding the instantiation of `MDExpansionPanel` objects inside an `if ... else` ternary conditional *expression* rather than the other way around.